# JSON Serialization using afnetworking

Tags: ios, json, node.js, swift, afnetworking-2

I have problem with the way i received the json in the server.
have students array (of dictionary) 
wrapping it in dictionary:

```
var students:[[String: String]] = []
students.append(["id":"2", "name":"joe"]);
students.append(["id":"3", "name":"jake"]);
students.append(["id":"4", "name":"may"]);
students.append(["id":"1", "name":"donna"]);
let json:[String:[[String:String]]] = ["students" : students]
```

when printing the json using NSJSONSerialization

```
var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options:  NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)
println(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

{
  "students" : [
    {
      "id" : "2",
      "name" : "joe"
    },
    {
      "id" : "3",
      "name" : "jake"
    },
    {
      "id" : "4",
      "name" : "may"
    },
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "name" : "donna"
    }
  ]
}
```

In `nodeJS` I get the json like this:

```
{ 'students[][id]': [ '2', '3', '4', '1'],
  'students[][name]': [ 'joe', 'jack', 'may', 'donna' ]
}
```

Edit: Afn code:

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager().POST("http://10.0.0.1:8080/echo", parameters: json,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
                println(operation.responseString)

            }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        })
```

Comment: There must be an issue on the server accepting the data. The JSON is formatted correctly, and you are serializing the data correctly. I'd look at your NodeJS install or code.

Comment: I'm using body-parser app.use(bodyParser.json()); and the first (and only thing) in the function is logging the req.body. Is it a configuration problem in the body-parser?

Comment: Can you verify that the data node is receiving is *exactly* the same as what you're showing? Just remove `app.use(bodyParser.json())` and instead use something like `app.use(function(req,res){req.pipe(process.stdout)})`

Comment: req.pipe(process.stdout)} logged : students[][id]=2&students[][name]=joe&
students[][id]=3&students[][name]=jack&
students[][id]=4&students[][name]=may&
students[][id]=1&students[][name]=donna

Comment: @Rob I added the AFN code. very simple, I use the default serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you are taking your dictionary structure, and manually creating JSON. But when you create the request via AFNetworking, you're not specifying a JSON request, but rather a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because the default `requestSerializer` is `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`.

If you want to create JSON request in AFNetworking, you would:

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer(writingOptions: nil)

manager.POST("http://10.0.0.1:8080/echo", parameters: json, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
    println(operation.responseString)

}, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    println(error)
})
```

Comment: Thank you :) this code fixed the problem : manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer(writingOptions: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros)

Comment: Yep, my initial rendition of my answer instantiated the serializer incorrectly (I'm too accustomed to using AFNetworking from Objective-C). I'd use the `nil` option, as shown in my revised answer, but use whatever writing options make sense for your app.

Comment: Hi @Rob, I'm trying to do the something (post json to the server) with post multipart, its changing the content type from "application/json" to "multipart/form-data".  but in the POST MULTI-PART REQUEST section in the docs (http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.0/) the do post a json: NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"} ..... [manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters.... .  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The main content-type of the request can be either multipart or it can be JSON. It can't be both. You could, theoretically, send multipart request where one of the parts was, itself, a JSON payload, but that's very weird way of doing it and I'd be _very_ surprised if that's how your server code was written. So, step back and take a look at how was the server code written. That will dictate how the request must be constructed.